# CSS resizes height/width in any resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build something thats going to run on TV screens, the resolution will be big but could be anything.

I've come up with the following HTML/CSS combo which almost works (however, if the height is too small the tables overlap the bottom of the footer and the padding to the right of the table overlaps the right hand side)

A JS Fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/hyLrj2t4/

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="flexbox-parent">
    <div class="flexbox-item header">
        Header
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item fill-area content flexbox-item-grow">
        <div class="fill-area-content flexbox-item-grow">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#FF0000">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#00FF00">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#0000FF">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#FF0000">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#00FF00">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#0000FF">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flexbox-item footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*, *:before, *:after
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body
{
    background: #444444;

    color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* Helvetica/Arial-based sans serif stack */
    font-family: Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", Univers, Calibri, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", Myriad, "DejaVu Sans Condensed", "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}

.flexbox-parent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */

    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.flexbox-item
{
    padding: 0.5%;
}
.flexbox-item-grow
{
    flex: 1; /* same as flex: 1 1 auto; */
}

.flexbox-item.header
{
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}
.flexbox-item.footer
{
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
}
.flexbox-item.content
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
}

.fill-area
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */

}
.fill-area-content
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border: 1px solid #000000;

    /* Needed for when the area gets squished too far and there is content that can't be displayed */
    overflow: auto; 
}

table{
    height:88%;
    position:absolute;
    }
```

The offending items can be seen here in the yellow squares:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the whole layout can be done without `flex` if I get it correctly, see simplified demo as follows.

http://jsfiddle.net/1yp2jh2t/

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-row;
}
.container > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.container > div:nth-child(2) > div {
    height: 100%;
}
.container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div><div>Header</div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr><td bgcolor="#FF0000"></td></tr>
                <tr><td bgcolor="#00FF00"></td></tr>
                <tr><td bgcolor="#0000FF"></td></tr>
                <tr><td bgcolor="#FF0000"></td></tr>
                <tr><td bgcolor="#00FF00"></td></tr>
                <tr><td bgcolor="#0000FF"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><div>Footer</div></div>
</div>
```